# How to fire concurrent requests using RSpec controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, rspec

I'm trying to fire 5 requests at the same time using threads and RSpec, but that gives me an `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` error. I think RSpec is sharing the same "context" for the requests.

```
context 'when the request is duplicated' do
  it 'blocks duplicate requests' do
    expect{

      threads = 5.times.map do
        Thread.new { post :checkout }
      end
      threads.map(&:join)

    }.to change{
      PaymentTransaction.count
    }.by(1)
  end
end
```

Is there any way to test concurrent requests using RSpec controller tests without raising this kind of exception, nor sharing the same "environment"?

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: @Anthony to test database locks, making sure that if I fire 5 concurrent requests, only 1 one them are being actually processed, avoiding duplicate calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems RSpec doesn't have an official solution to this. To solve this, I've rescued the `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` exception inside the Thread. That solved it, therefore it's not the most elegant solution.

```
context 'when the request is duplicated' do
  it 'blocks duplicate requests' do
    expect{

      threads = 5.times.map do
        Thread.new do
          post :checkout
        rescue AbstractController::DoubleRenderError
        end
      end
      threads.map(&:join)

    }.to change{
      PaymentTransaction.count
    }.by(1)
  end
end
```